# How do I create an infinite function loop? (PHP)

Tags: php

Here's the actual function

```
$linkArray = array(//associative array for title and url of site and etc
        "url"=>"",
        "title"=>"",
        "num"=>""
    );
    $site = $_POST['link'];
    function parseLink($link){
        global $conn;//reinitialize conn variable b/c inside fn it's unknown unless reinitialized       
        //get title of page
        $page_title = get_url_title($link);
        //1-Get HTML content
        $html = file_get_contents($link);
        $a_tag = preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+>/i', $html, $result);
        $i = 0;//dummy var
        //check if we get result
        if($a_tag > 0){
            while($i < $a_tag){
                $alink = $result[0][$i];
                preg_match_all('/(href)=("[^"]*")/i',$alink, $href);
                $hreflnk = $href[0][0];
                $hreflnk = str_replace('href="',"",$hreflnk);
                $hreflnk = substr($hreflnk, 0, -1);
                //filter out only links that start with http -> this will automatically include https
                //$randomvar = preg_match("/^http/i",$hreflnk,$outp);
                if(preg_match("/^http/i",$hreflnk)){
                    $hreflnk = $hreflnk;
                } else{
                    //idk
                    $hreflnk = '';
                }
                $linkArray['url'][$i] = $hreflnk;
                $linkArray['title'] = $page_title;
                $linkArray['num'] = $a_tag;

                $siteTitle = $linkArray['title'];
                $numLinks = $linkArray['num'];
                $siteUrl = $linkArray['url'][$i];
                $queryI = $conn->query("INSERT INTO data (title, url, numLinks) VALUES ('$siteTitle','$siteUrl','$numLinks')");
                $outLink = $linkArray['url'][0];
                $i++;
            }

        }

        return $outLink;
    }
```

This function takes in a URL searches through the HTML and stores all `http` links in array and later uploads them to a db. Before it ends it returns the first link of all of those that were collected. So what I want to do is run that link back into this function. Then this process will repeat.

Comment: What's going to change `$input`?

Comment: Client application or site?

Comment: The stuff that the function test does. It will change it to `$output`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use a recursive function:

```
function foo($i = 0) {
    if ($i == 100) {
        return 'yay';
    } else {
        $i++;
        return foo($i);
    }
}
foo();
```

Alternatively, do you *really* need a repeating function?

```
$i = 0;
while($i != 100) {
    $i++;
}
```

or:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $i++;
} while ($i != 100);
```

With a string:

```
do {
    $recordString = DB::get()->getRow('SELECT `name` from `username` ORDER BY RAND()')->getField('name');
} while ($recordString != 'admin') {

//$recordString will now 100% be 'admin', unless you time out during the execution
```

**Edit**:

With your new question update, I'd propose you to change your code to the following:

```
<?php
    function parseLink($link, $outLinks = array()){
        global $conn;//reinitialize conn variable b/c inside fn it's unknown unless reinitialized       
        //get title of page
        $page_title = get_url_title($link);
        //1-Get HTML content
        $html = file_get_contents($link);

        $document = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
        foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
            $href = $element->getAttribute('href');

            if (!isset($outLinks[$href])) { //don't redo ones we've already done
                $linkArray['url'][$i] = $href;
                $linkArray['title'] = $page_title;
                $linkArray['num'] = $i;

                $siteTitle = $linkArray['title'];
                $numLinks = $linkArray['num'];
                $siteUrl = $linkArray['url'][$i];
                $queryI = $conn->query("INSERT INTO data (title, url, numLinks) VALUES ('$siteTitle','$siteUrl','$numLinks')");
                $outLinks[$href] = $linkArray['url'][0];
                $i++;
            }
        }

        foreach ($outLinks as $href => $dbID) {
            $outsLinks = parseLink($href, $outLinks);
        }

        return $outLinks;
    }
?>
```

**Changes**:

- Used `DOMDocument` instead, as regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML.
- Changed `$outLink` to use the array `$outLinks` which it returns.

Comment: Hey "h2ooooooo"! What you are doing is adding number, right? What I have is a string that the function takes in and outputs another string.

Comment: @user3339439 You could still use a `while()` or a `do while()` without a problem. Just do something while you string isn't X.

Comment: @user3339439 I've added a string example if that helps you.

Comment: @user3339439 Change your question to your actual code (where you generate whatever string it is you need to be *X*), and I'll guide you out. :)

Comment: Ok. I didnt want it to be a hassle for you guys. Now I will :)

Comment: Few questions:
1) Is the infinite loop being created here?
2) Why no regex when parsing HTML?
3) `$outLinks` is an array now right? - YES (never saw-my bad)

Comment: @user3339439 Nope - you don't need an infinite loop unless you want to crawl all subsites as well - is that what you want?

Comment: @user3339439 Yeah - the site parsed to `parseLink()` by the `$link` variable.

Comment: Ok but I want to crawl the site url that it would output!
And why `if (!isset($outLinks[$href]))`?

Comment: @user3339439 Do you want to do this for every site URL? Eg. "*page a has a link to page b, so crawl page b - page b has a link to page c, so crawl page c - page c has a link to page d so call page d......*", or only crawl *sub* links that you find with `praseLink`? The condition is to make sure that we don't go through links we already have - it'd be a waste of resources. Since we already added it to the `$outLinks` array by the `$href` value, we can check if they exist already.

Comment: "page a has a link to page b, so crawl page b - page b has a link to page c, so crawl page c - page c has a link to page d so call page d" I want to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3339439 I've edited my post again with the infinite loop. Keep in mind that PHP is not a very good crawler, and if you do this it might halt the PHP compiler when executing as this might take a *veeeeeeery* long time.

Comment: Aren't you just going to hit max execution time?

Comment: @vascowhite There isn't necessarily a max execution time if this is run in the command line console, or something similar (`set_time_limit(0)`).

Comment: Ah, ok, just a thought.

Comment: @vascowhite That said, I would not expect OP to run this for every user every time they request the site. It would destroy the sites performance completely.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Probably just as we'll that you have stated that though ;)

Comment: @user3339439 Watch out by the way - all your database fields are going in un-escaped, which means that 1. your db can be hacked and 2. if there's any `'` character in the title, URL or anything else it's going to fail.

Comment: Yes, this is just for me playing around. Not any real application for any real life purpose right now. Still thanks, I never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($myvar) $myvar = test($myvar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$value = "Initial value";

function test($input){
  // does stuff inside
  // sets output to false if blank
  return $output;
}

while($value) {
  // runs until test returns false or an empty string
  $value = test($value);
}
```